# Can I add a parameter to a Route::group in Laravel but remove it before dispatching to a route in Laravel?

Tags: php, rest, laravel, laravel-4

I am using Laravel 4 to create APIs namespaced by `accountname` of each of my customers.  Each customer has their own, identical database.  So Foocorp should make api calls that look like this:

> http://api.example.com/Foocorp/users/5

Barcorp api calls look like this

> http://api.example.com/Barcorp/users/5

I must include the account name in the URL for business/branding reasons, so I cannot eliminate this parameter from the URL routes.

Here is a filter that I was using to attempt to pull out the account name from the route, verify it is active, and point to their database.  I hoped to remove the `accountname` parameter so that I could write all my controller functions to not include an `$accountname` parameter for all of them.

```
Route::filter('accountverification', function()
{
    $route = Route::getCurrentRoute();
    $params = $route->getParameters();
    $accountName = $params['accountname'];

    // verify account with this name exists and set up DB connection to point to their database
    // ...

    unset($params['accountname']);
    $route->setParameters($params);
});
```

Here's my route group that uses the filter:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => '{accountname}', 'before' => 'accountverification'), function() {
    Route::get('users/{id}', 'UsersController@getShow')
        ->where(array('id' => '[0-9]+'));
});
```

The problem is that removing the parameter in the filter does not have any effect when controller/function is called.  In the UsersController::getShow function the first parameter is always the `accountname` from the group prefix.

Is there a way for me to include a variable/parameter in all my routes that I can do something with before the request is dispatched, which won't be passed to the function?

Comment: I have a hacky workaround where I have a base controller that registers a beforeFilter in its constructor to pull the accountname parameter out and set up the database.  Then I override the callMethod to do an array_shift on the $parameters array before calling the parent callMethod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the right way to use filters. In fact, if you define a filter "accountname" then that's the name of the filter - but you're using "accountverification".

What you should do is, in your UsersController constructor, check the account name. Your route prefix must be a known value.

Comment: The "accountname" vs "accountverification" was a typo -- thanks for catching that.  I guess what I'm saying is that every one of my functions needs to be scoped to an account.  I'd like to know if there is a way I can handle this globally without requiring every one of my functions to be defined to include the $accountname parameter.  This parameter causes the database connection to point to the correct database but beyond that it has no effect on business logic and will essentially be an unused parameter in every controller function.

Comment: I think I followed what you're saying.  I'm not sure if it's ideal, but in addition to checking the account name in the constructor I am shifting off the first parameter in an overridden callMethod function.  This way the individual functions inside don't need to define an $accountname parameter.

Comment: Throw your logic into the `BaseController`'s constructor perhaps?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can. Use the route function: `forgetParameter($parameter)` to remove the parameter from being included into the arguments on your controllers. This function is available in laravel 4.1 or greater. For your example:

```
Route::filter('accountverification', function(Route $route)
{
    $params = $route->getParameters();
    $accountName = $params['accountname'];

// verify account with this name exists and set up DB connection to point to their database
// ...

    $route->forgetParameter('accountname');
});
```

For example, I use this for forgetting a `locale` parameter in my routes so it's not included as an argument on every controller method inside the route group.

http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Routing/Route.html#method_forgetParameter

Please leave a comment in the future if this link becomes broken, as I'll update when necessary.

**EDIT**:

In Laravel 5, you can use middleware to do this as well since Route filters are depreciated.